# Why there is input delay (textarea) in React when setting background image?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

The components are independent, when I press keyboard there is a super delay in the input, when I remove the background image, there is no delay. is this cause by the background image re-render?

When I keep input the cpu usage is very high and the numbers of DOM nodes start to increase:

[image]

main.jsx:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
    },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

home.jsx

```
export default function Home() {
    const style = {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100dvh', // dvh: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sF5KsEo6gM
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        zIndex: -1,
    }

    return (
        <div style={style}>
            <InputBar/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

inputbar.jsx

```
export default function InputBar() {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    function onChange(e) {
        setText(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <textarea
                onChange={onChange}
                value={text}
                placeholder={'Say something...'}>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Stack Snippet:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const backgroundImage = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQGGM.jpg";

function Home() {
    const style = {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100dvh', // dvh: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sF5KsEo6gM
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        zIndex: -1,
    }

    return (
        <div style={style}>
            <InputBar/>
        </div>
    )
}

function InputBar() {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    function onChange(e) {
        setText(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <textarea
                onChange={onChange}
                value={text}
                placeholder={'Say something...'}>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Home />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the `style` object outside the component so that it's not a new object every time? Nothing in it uses anything dynamic. (That said, I wouldn't expect `Home` to be re-rendering anyway...)

Comment: The state lives in `InputBar` component so typing doesn't rerender `Home` component, so `style` object should not be a problem in this case.

Comment: Does it have the same issue if you have an uncontrolled textarea? (`<textarea />` without a `value` and `onChange`)

Comment: I've updated your question to copy the code into a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/), using a background image from a placeholder site. It doesn't have the problem you describe. Please update the Snippet so that it demonstrates the problem you're having. (Please be sure to post the image to the question via SO's image partner as I have in the example, rather than direct linking to an off-site image.)

Comment: @JakubKotrs first time I used `<textarea />` directly, I found it very slow then I changed to the `useState()` but has some effect, very slow,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I have tried, actually I used a style component called `BackgroundImage` which is just a `div` with same style as shown in the `home`, I thought it was that I have a separate style component causes input slow, so I removed the component and add background image  in Home component directly.

Comment: @ShaowenZhu - Well, as I said (and Jakub also said), `Home` shouldn't be re-rendering anyway so it wasn't a great thought (well, he didn't say that, but I will :-) ). Right now, we can't help you with this, because we can't see it happen. Please see [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78160653/why-there-is-input-delay-textarea-in-react-when-setting-background-image?noredirect=1#comment137794482_78160653) about an MRE. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your help, I solved this problem by changing a smaller size background image, the original size is 17MB, now its ~800KB, there is no delay now, but this is weird...

Comment: @ShaowenZhu - That is very weird, I don't see why that would be causing a delay like that. Can you add the 17MB image to the question? (Or does it hit a size limit, I wouldn't be surprised if there was one...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, More weird thing is that on Safari (Mobile and Mac) there is no delay, on Arc (similar to Chrome) and Edge there is input delay. I don't know how to upload original quality image on Stackoverflow, I have upload the file to my server: https://raven1132.com?file_id=cb91cbb5b60be7f6145ee7c550ae27372ab90f84687d56c6ab435ebae2ed76f2

Comment: @ShaowenZhu - Yeah, the limit for SO's imgur is 2MB. If I use that URL directly in the Stack Snippet above I can replicate the problem you're having. I'm glad reducing it to 800k fixes it.